# Reflectively look at a variable name, rather than value

Tags: java, reflection

Given the class:

```
class Statics {
  public static String LOC_MY_SELECTOR;

  static void find(String selector) {
    System.out.println(selector);
  }  

  public static void main(String...args) {
    find(LOC_MY_SELECTOR);
  }
}
```

How am I able to, at the point of `System.out.println` get the field name, rather than the value?  The value is `null`, so of course it will print out null.  What I want to do, is:

```
find(LOC_MY_SELECTOR); // to print "LOC_MY_SELECTOR" instead of the value `null`
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: No, and why would you even want to do that?

Comment: *If* you know that the value comes from a static field of a known class, then you could, but it sounds like a terrible design. Are you sure you don't just want to use [an enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: I want to dynamically populate the `LOC_MY_SELECTOR` field upon reference, rather than give it an initial value

Comment: Use some kind of lazy evaluator.

Comment: it's possible that i just need to use an enum.  assuming that someone can provide a definitive "yes" or "no" to this being possible, and providing a POC if it is, then i'll keep this open.  if it's bad design - I wouldn't mind changing it to fit more appropriate conventions :)

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. If it's just _to print "LOC_MY_SELECTOR" instead of the value `null`_, than the answer is No.

Comment: the context is - without assigning *LOC_MY_SELECTOR*, I'd like to - upon reference - return a new string based on the field name.  so, *LOC_MY_SELECTOR* would actually return `my_selector`.  I can do this using `java.lang.reflect.Field`, however not at the point of reference.

Comment: Why do you even need the field? Just return the string `"my_selector"`.

Comment: see my answer.  please source your material next time @SotiriosDelimanolis.  nevertheless, i appreciate you and everyone else attempting to help me out `:)`  it's why i love this site.

Comment: Even with your answer, it's still completely unclear what you're trying to do. Of course you can assign the value of the name of a field (a `String`) to a variable of type `String`. What you're doing seems completely useless to me, though. Just initialize `LOC_MY_SELECTOR = "my_selector";` Why would you want an identifier that self identifies?

Comment: purely convenience - for testers that aren't programmers.  this allows them to have one less junction for error.  *LOC_MY_SELECTOR = "my_selectr"* (missing the 'o' breaks the script).  this "helps" (Granted, i know - not much) reduce the human error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is "yes you can."

I figured this out by populating the static fields in the class constructor.  Then every subsequent reference, the field will already be set.

```
class Statics {
  public static String LOC_MY_SELECTOR;

  public Statics() {
    Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
      int mods = field.getModifiers();
      if (field.getType() == String.class &&
        !Modifier.isFinal(mods) &&
        Modifier.isStatic(mods) &&
        Modifier.isPublic(mods) &&
        field.getName().startsWith("LOC_")
      ) {

        String fieldName = field.getName();
        field.setAccessible(true);

        try {
          // homepage_
          String translation = fieldName.split("_", 2)[1].toLowerCase();

          field.set(field, translation);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static void find(String selector) {
    System.out.println(selector);
  }  

  public static void main(String...args) {
    find(LOC_MY_SELECTOR);
    // will print "my_selector" now
  }
}
```